# Error when using WHERE in Eve-SQLAlchemy: TypeError: find() got an unexpected keyword argument 'perform_count'

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, eve

I'm using Eve-SQLAlchemy to access data in SQLite database. I have a `People` class:

```
class People(BaseModel):
    '''Test class'''
    __tablename__ = 'people'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = Column(String)
    lastname = Column(String)
    born = Column(Date)
```

REST API works nicely with this query:

```
curl -s http://127.0.0.1:5000/people/1

{
    "id": 1,
    "firstname": "Isaac",
    "lastname": "Newton",
    "born": "1642-12-25",
    "_updated": "Fri, 19 Apr 2019 14:03:08 GMT",
    "_created": "Fri, 19 Apr 2019 14:03:08 GMT",
    "_etag": "69a44481049920b40b7c06e651ed6c561f8b4892",
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "title": "People",
            "href": "people/1"
        },
        "parent": {
            "title": "home",
            "href": "/"
        },
        "collection": {
            "title": "people",
            "href": "people"
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I try to use `WHERE`:

```
curl -s 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/people?where={"firstname":"Isaac"}'
```

I get this in server console:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Nov/2019 17:23:05] "GET /people?where="firstname":"Isaac" HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mark/projects/nlp_pipeline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eve/flaskapp.py", line 1106, in __call__
    return super(Eve, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/mark/projects/nlp_pipeline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/mark/projects/nlp_pipeline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/mark/projects/nlp_pipeline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/mark/projects/nlp_pipeline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/mark/projects/nlp_pipeline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/mark/projects/nlp_pipeline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/mark/projects/nlp_pipeline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/mark/projects/nlp_pipeline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/mark/projects/nlp_pipeline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/mark/projects/nlp_pipeline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/mark/projects/nlp_pipeline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eve/endpoints.py", line 56, in collections_endpoint
    response = get(resource, lookup)
  File "/home/mark/projects/nlp_pipeline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eve/methods/common.py", line 318, in rate_limited
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mark/projects/nlp_pipeline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eve/auth.py", line 80, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mark/projects/nlp_pipeline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eve/methods/common.py", line 1354, in decorated
    r = f(resource, **combined_args)
  File "/home/mark/projects/nlp_pipeline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eve/methods/get.py", line 51, in get
    return get_internal(resource, **lookup)
  File "/home/mark/projects/nlp_pipeline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eve/methods/get.py", line 125, in get_internal
    return _perform_find(resource, lookup)
  File "/home/mark/projects/nlp_pipeline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eve/methods/get.py", line 266, in _perform_find
    resource, req, lookup, perform_count=not config.OPTIMIZE_PAGINATION_FOR_SPEED
TypeError: find() got an unexpected keyword argument 'perform_count'
```

What's the reason and how can I fix that?

Python 3.7, package versions:

```
Eve==0.9.2
Eve-SQLAlchemy==0.7.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.1
SQLAlchemy==1.3.11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Eve-SQLAlchemy with a **not yet supported version of Eve**. Eve-SQLAlchemy 0.7.1 supports `Eve<0.8`, but you are using `Eve==0.9.2`

Running `pip install .` in Eve-SQLAlchemy's root directory should install the correct dependencies, including `Eve==0.7.10`.